# Why does rxjs concat produce different values when passed and array instead of individual arguments?

Tags: angular, rxjs, operator-keyword, concatenation

rxjs docs state that the concat operator can take individual arguments of observables or an array. When I pass individual arguments, I get what I would expect. The observable returned from concat has all the values from each of the observables in the observable that it returns sequenced as they should be. Here is an example with individual parameters and it working as expected:

```
        var str: string = "";
        var obs1: Observable<string> = of("hello");
        var obs2: Observable<string> = of("world");
        concat(obs1, obs2).subscribe(
            s => str += s as string + " ",
            err => {},
            () => str.trim()
        )
```

When this runs, str will be "hello world"

When I pass an array of observables, it returns [object Object] for each value instead of the value of the observable. Can anyone tell me why this is and how to get concat working with an array? Here is the above example using an array:

```
        var str: string = "";
        var strBuild: Observable<string>[] = [];
        strBuild.push(of("hello"));
        strBuild.push(of("world"));
        concat(strBuild).subscribe(
            s => str += s as string + " ",
            err => {},
            () => str.trim()
        )
```

When this runs, str will be "[object Object] [object Object]"

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `s` is still an observable since `strBuild` is an array of 2 `Observable`, and not an `Observable` of an array of strings. There probably better options, but a possibility is to subscribe to each observable: in the `concat()` like so:

```
concat(strBuild).subscribe(
    s => s.subscribe(e => str += e + " "), //s is an Observable so we need to subscribe
    err => {},
    () => str.trim()
)
```

I'm just explaining the reason for the different output in your examples, but I'm sure there's a better approach to build array of strings with `Observables`

Comment: Wow, you're right! That works, but it makes no sense to me why it works that way. I would expect the array to be an alternative to the variadic form. In fact, I don't see how that's any different than just calling .subscribe method directly on each 'of' method but then you lose the sequential guarantee. So, really, the only way to ensure a set of observables complete sequentially is if there are only a handful of them and they are already known and individually passed into concat. The array form is essentially worthless.

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like there are open issues about this:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4203 and https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4697

Comment: Bottom line is that to get the behvior I would expect you have to use the rest operator like this `concat(...strBuild)`